# How to pass data between wsgi middleware?

Tags: python, middleware, wsgi

I'm trying to make a chain of the middlewares and I have to pass data between them. I would like to have the variables that live during the request/response lifecycle. At this moment I use `environ` argument and add to it the data. But it seems that this is a wrong way.
Example:

```
class A(object):
    """First class in a sequence"""
    def __call__(self, app):
        # logic here
        def some_func(environ, start_response):
            # logic here
            environ['my key'] = 'some data'
            def custom_headers(status, headers, exc_info=None):
                # change headers
                return start_response(status, headers, exc_info)
            return app(environ, custom_headers)
        return some_func

class B(object):
    """Second class in a sequence"""
    def __call__(self, app):
        # logic here
        def some_func(environ, start_response):
            data = environ.get('my key')
            # logic here

            def custom_headers(status, headers, exc_info=None):
                # change headers
                return start_response(status, headers, exc_info)
            return app(environ, custom_headers)
        return some_func
```

So as you can see I would like to generate a data in one class and after that treat it in the second one(**!data should be unique** per each **request/response** not shared between them).

Could you help to find the best way to do it?